# killing a thread without waiting for join

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to kill a thread in python. This thread can run in a blocking operation and join can't terminate it.

Simular to this:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def block():
    while True:
        print("running")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        thread = Thread(target = block)
        thread.start()
        #kill thread
        #do other stuff
```

My problem is that the real blocking operation is in another module that is not from me so there is no place where I can break with a running variable.

Comment: If you don't want to terminate the process (as Netwave proposed) this would need OS specific measures and brings the Python interpreter to an undefined state where it may crash, freeze or anything else.

Comment: Re, "...and join can't terminate it." That's not what `join()` is for.  Calling `t.join()` is not supposed to do _anything at all_ to thread `t`.  The only thing it does is _wait_ until thread `t` terminates for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

The thread will be killed when exiting the main process if you set it up as a daemon:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def block():
    while True:
        print("running")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        thread = Thread(target = block, daemon = True)
        thread.start()
        sys.exit(0)
```

Otherwise just set a flag, I'm using a **bad example** (you should use some synchronization not just a plain variable):

```
from threading import Thread
import time
RUNNING = True
def block():
    global RUNNING
    while RUNNING:
        print("running")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        thread = Thread(target = block, daemon = True)
        thread.start()
        RUNNING = False # thread will stop, not killed until next loop iteration
        .... continue your stuff here
```

Comment: my problem is that the real blocking operation is in an other module that is not from me so there is no place where I can break with a running variable

Comment: There is no way of killing a thread that is not under your control (at least from a high level perspective)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `running` variable:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

running = True

def block():
    global running
    while running:
        print("running")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        thread = Thread(target = block)
        thread.start()

        running = False

        # do other stuff
```

I would prefer to wrap it all in a class, but this should work (untested though).

Comment: my problem is that the real blocking operation is in an other module that is not from me so there is no place where I can break with a running variable

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

There is a way to asynchronously raise an exception in a separate thread which could be caught by a `try: except:` block, but it's a dirty dirty hack: https://gist.github.com/liuw/2407154

**Original post**

"I want to kill a thread in python." you can't. Threads are only killed when they're daemons when there are no more non-daemonic threads running from the parent process. Any thread can be asked nicely to terminate itself using standard inter-thread communication methods, but you state that you don't have any chance to interrupt the function you want to kill. This leaves processes.

Processes have more overhead, and are more difficult to pass data to and from, but they do support being killed by sending SIGTERM or SIGKILL.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep

def workfunction(*args, **kwargs): #any arguments you send to a child process must be picklable by python's pickle module
    sleep(args[0]) #really long computation you might want to kill
    return 'results' #anything you want to get back from a child process must be picklable by python's pickle module


class daemon_worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, target_func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.return_queue = Queue()
        self.target_func = target_func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.start()

    def run(self): #called by self.start()
        self.return_queue.put(self.target_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs))


    def get_result(self): #raises queue.Empty if no result is ready
        return self.return_queue.get()


if __name__=='__main__':
    #start some work that takes 1 sec:
    worker1 = daemon_worker(workfunction, 1)
    worker1.join(3) #wait up to 3 sec for the worker to complete
    if not worker1.is_alive(): #if we didn't hit 3 sec timeout
        print('worker1 got: {}'.format(worker1.get_result()))
    else:
        print('worker1 still running')
        worker1.terminate()
        print('killing worker1')
        sleep(.1) #calling worker.is_alive() immediately might incur a race condition where it may or may not have shut down yet.
        print('worker1 is alive: {}'.format(worker1.is_alive()))

    #start some work that takes 100 sec:
    worker2 = daemon_worker(workfunction, 100)
    worker2.join(3) #wait up to 3 sec for the worker to complete
    if not worker2.is_alive(): #if we didn't hit 3 sec timeout
        print('worker2 got: {}'.format(worker2.get_result()))
    else:
        print('worker2 still running')
        worker2.terminate()
        print('killing worker2')
        sleep(.1) #calling worker.is_alive() immediately might incur a race condition where it may or may not have shut down yet.
        print('worker2 is alive: {}'.format(worker2.is_alive())
```